Will SQLite allow me to lock in a custom way when using Virtual Tables?
In most of my web apps I use sqlite, I really find it amazing for most-reads/less-writes database.
I just found lately the Virtual Tables mechanism which I can use to support SQLite's SQL statements in an external way to save/load data, outside of the database.
The question is, will SQLite allow me to lock the database the way I want? For example, when there's an INSERT statement into a virtual table under my control, will it lock the whole database file as it would do when inserting into a common table?
If yes, then virtual tables are useless to me, but if no, I could try to implement a multi-user writing system based on row locking, not the entire database.
Thanks for your advice.

Right.  If locks the whole file.  If you need a multi-user solution, then you need to be using a real database server, like MySQL or Postgres.  SQLite is intentionally simple and was not intended for sophisticated multi-user scenarios.
